# Spring Boot and Spring Data with Cassandra: Continue on failed database connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I use Spring Boot and Spring Data with Cassandra. On application startup spring establishes a connection to the database to setup the schema and initialize spring data repositories. If the database is not available, the application won't start.

I want, that the application just logs an error and starts. Of course, I can't use the repositories anymore, but other services (rest controllers etc), which are independent from the database should work. It would also be nice to see in actuator healthcheck, that cassandra is down.

For JDBC, there is a `spring.datasource.continue-on-error` property. I couldn't find something similar for Cassandra.

I also tried to create a custom cassandra configuration and trying to catch Exception on CqlSession creation, but I couldn't achieve the desired behavior.

EDIT: As suggested by @adutra, I tried to set [advanced.reconnect-on-init](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/core/configuration/reference/), Application tries to establish the connection, but the application is not fully initialized (e.g. REST controller are not reachable)

```
@Configuration
public class CustomCassandraConfiguration extends CassandraAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer driverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.RECONNECT_ON_INIT, true);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: I have now working example (application starts, custom health check for cassandra), but if feels pretty ugly:

CustomCassandraAutoConfiguration

```js
@Configuration
public class CustomCassandraAutoConfiguration extends CassandraAutoConfiguration {
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
@Bean
public CqlSession cassandraSession(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
    try {
        return super.cassandraSession(cqlSessionBuilder);
    } catch (AllNodesFailedException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to establish the database connection", e);
    }
    return new DatabaseNotConnectedFakeCqlSession();
}

@Bean
public CassandraReactiveHealthIndicator cassandraHealthIndicator(ReactiveCassandraOperations r, CqlSession session) {
    if (session instanceof DatabaseNotConnectedFakeCqlSession) {
        return new CassandraReactiveHealthIndicator(r) {
            @Override
            protected Mono<Health> doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) {
                return Mono.just(builder.down().withDetail("connection", "was not available on startup").build());
            }
        };
    }
    return new CassandraReactiveHealthIndicator(r);
}
}
```

CustomCassandraDataAutoConfiguration

```js
@Configuration
public class CustomCassandraDataAutoConfiguration extends CassandraDataAutoConfiguration {

public CustomCassandraDataAutoConfiguration(CqlSession session) {
    super(session);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactoryFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactory(CqlSession session, Environment environment, CassandraConverter converter) {
    SessionFactoryFactoryBean sessionFactoryFactoryBean = super.cassandraSessionFactory(environment, converter);

    // Disable schema action if database is not available
    if (session instanceof DatabaseNotConnectedFakeCqlSession) {
        sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    }
    return sessionFactoryFactoryBean;
}
}
```

DatabaseNotConnectedFakeCqlSession (Fake session implementation)

```js
public class DatabaseNotConnectedFakeCqlSession implements CqlSession {
   
@Override
public String getName() {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public Metadata getMetadata() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isSchemaMetadataEnabled() {
    return false;
}

   
@Override
public CompletionStage<Metadata> setSchemaMetadataEnabled( Boolean newValue) {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public CompletionStage<Metadata> refreshSchemaAsync() {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public CompletionStage<Boolean> checkSchemaAgreementAsync() {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public DriverContext getContext() {
    return new DefaultDriverContext(new DefaultDriverConfigLoader(), ProgrammaticArguments.builder().build());
}

   
@Override
public Optional<CqlIdentifier> getKeyspace() {
    return Optional.empty();
}

   
@Override
public Optional<Metrics> getMetrics() {
    return Optional.empty();
}


@Override
public <RequestT extends Request, ResultT> ResultT execute( RequestT request, GenericType<ResultT> resultType) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public CompletionStage<Void> closeFuture() {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public CompletionStage<Void> closeAsync() {
    return null;
}

   
@Override
public CompletionStage<Void> forceCloseAsync() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Metadata refreshSchema() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I also tried to create a custom cassandra configuration and trying to catch Exception on CqlSession creation, but I couldn't achieve the desired behavior." Why? If you declare another bean of type CqlSession the default one declared in CassandraAutoConfiguration won't be used; then you are free to create your session as you like, so I'm surprised that you couldn't catch the exception thrown by SessionBuilder.build().

Comment: @adutra: I created own implementation of CqlSession, but there is to many dependencies. Many getter must return valid values (otherwise NPE). I think, this would be possible to implement all necessary methods, but it feels like a hack and I try to find more elegant solution.

Comment: You don't need to implement CqlSession. I was suggesting to catch the exception: public CqlSession cassandraSession(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
  try {
    return cqlSessionBuilder.build();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}

Comment: If null will be returned instead of CqlSession, this will break the application: all components which get Repositories per "Autowired" can't be instantiated. Also Spring autoconfiguration is broken "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reactiveCassandraSession'".

Comment: Indeed. If your bean can be null, you can't inject it directly. You need to wrap it into an Optional, or better yet, ObjectProvider: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html

Answer (score 6):

You can set the option `datastax-java-driver.advanced.reconnect-on-init` to true to achieve the effect you want. Its usage is explained in the [configuration reference page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.8/manual/core/configuration/reference/) in the driver docs:

> Whether to schedule reconnection attempts if all contact points are unreachable on the first initialization attempt.
> If this is true, the driver will retry according to the reconnection policy. The `SessionBuilder.build()` call - or the future returned by `SessionBuilder.buildAsync()` - won't complete until a contact point has been reached. If this is false and no contact points are available, the driver will fail with an `AllNodesFailedException`.

However be careful: with this option set to true, as stated above, any component trying to access a `CqlSession` bean, *even if the session bean is lazy*, will block until the driver is able to connect, and might block forever if the contact points are wrong.

If that's not acceptable for you, I would suggest that you wrap the `CqlSession` bean in another bean that will check if the future returned by `SessionBuilder.buildAsync()` is done or not, and either block, throw or return null, depending on the caller's expectations.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I'll try it.

Comment: I would second this here is a similar question that comes to the same CqlSession path.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215539/why-cant-get-a-connection-to-cassandra-running-on-docker-from-a-spring-boot-ins

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** I've reached out internally to the DataStax Drivers team last night and adutra has responded so I'm withdrawing my response.

Comment: No, it is not. It could be a case that someone needs application keep running with some functionality without database, some monolith, or dynamic database case. Also, it is viable not to be dependent on some bean initialization like datasource

Comment: It depends on the use case: sometimes it is better to have a "fail-fast" system, if an external dependency (database, messaging provider etc) is not available, the application start should fail immediate. But sometimes you may have an application which hast e.g. 3 different external dependencies. And if one is not available -> it is ok to report the error and start.